# Invalidity of awk printf in bash script

Tags: bash, awk

Why does the construction of the `printf` not valid?

```
awk -v frg="$ctp" -v rst="$sgr" -v prl="$rl"  \
  '{ hit = match($0, /prl/)
     if (hit) {
       fm="%s%s%s\n" ; printf fm frg $0 rst }
     else {
       fm="%s\n" ; printf fm $0 }
   }' <<< "$@"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -v frg="$ctp" -v rst="$sgr" -v prl="$rl" '
{ hit = match($0, prl)
  if (hit) {
    fm="%s%s%s\n" ; printf fm, frg, $0, rst }
  else {
    fm="%s\n" ; printf fm, $0 
  }
}' <<< "$@"
```

Corrections:

- `match($0, /prl/)` changed to `match($0, prl)`
- `printf` parameters must be separated with comma

Note: The second augment to the match() function is regexp, you might want to use *`index(in, find)`* function instead for literal matching on *prl*.

You could also use regular awk regexp matching too instead of match() like `$0 ~ prl` (again if you want regexp match and assuming there is no regexp character `/` in your pattern).

```
awk -v frg="$ctp" -v rst="$sgr" -v prl="$rl" '
{ 
  if ($0 ~ prl) {
    fm="%s%s%s\n" ; printf fm, frg, $0, rst }
  else {
    fm="%s\n" ; printf fm, $0
  }
}' <<< "$@"
```

Similarly and finally simplifying your code, you could write:

```
awk -v frg="$ctp" -v rst="$sgr" -v prl="$rl" '
  { print ($0 ~ prl ? frg $0 rst: $0 }
' <<< "$@"
```

Comment: Have been using `rl="^ Some.*$"` on a multiline variable bet am not getting a match on lines starting with space followed by `Some` and any other characters following that.

Comment: @Gibran I don't see that in your question. that might be your another question somewhere or you may want to [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/735128/edit) and tell us what is that and how you are trying it and how that doesn't work which is far from your what expected input(s)/output(s).

Comment: Let us forget my comment about `rl` then.  Could you elaborate on the use of `index(in, find)` function instead for literal matching on `prl`.  What would be the advantages?

Comment: @Gibran The advantage is that you would be able to find strings that look like regular expressions without having to escape "active" characters like `.` and `*`. It would also be quicker as substring matching is much simpler that regular expression matching.

Comment: @Gibran it's not about advantage of one to another. each one has its own functionality and can be used based on your need. As I said _`match(string, regexp)`_ function can be used to look for the  matching ___regexp___  in the _string_; while the _`index(string, find)`_ can be used to look for the matching ___find___ string as _literal string_ match in the ___string___. read more about awk string-functions [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

Comment: ... BTW, as you read, in some awk implementations you can however pass regexp as the second argument to the index() function too.

Comment: @αғsнιη `index()` never takes a regexp as it's second arg in any awk implementation.

Comment: @EdMorton that is what [GNU awk manual said](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) (emphasize mine) as a dark-corner: "_With **BWK** awk and **gawk**, it is a fatal error to use a regexp constant for find. **Other implementations allow it**, simply treating the regexp constant as an expression meaning `‘$0 ~ /regexp/’`. (d.c.)_" BTW I never used any other awk other than GNU awk and so I trusted the manual.

Comment: That doesn't mean index() takes a regexp constant as it's second argument, it means if you put a regexp constant in that spot it will be interpreted **before index() is called** as either a fatal error which results in the script exiting, or as if you wrote `$0 ~ /regexp/` which results in index() being called with either 1 or 0 as it's second arg. In neither case will you be passing a regexp as the second argument to the index() function.

Comment: @EdMorton that doesn't mean the same thing(?) forgetting what is processing when doing like that. it means some implementations allows the regexp in 2nd argument even if we now know it's not a process of the index() call directly but a final result happened as a regexp match.

Comment: No. The final result would happen if the regexp matched in $0, not the first arg to index(), and then `1` existed in the first arg to index(), or the regexp did not match in $0, not the first arg to index(), and then `0` existed in the first arg to index(). In neither case is the regexp used as the 2nd arg to index(). The regexp could match against $0 or not, it'll never be compared to the first arg to index(), and then index() might return a number as the index in it's first arg of either 0 or 1 regardless of whatever the regexp was.

Comment: The 2nd arg to index() isn't the regexp, it's the result of comparing the regexp to $0. It's like if you write `foo = /regexp/` - you're not saving a regexp in `foo`, you're saving the result of comparing `regexp` to `$0` in `foo`. It's like writing `foo = ( $0 ~ /regexp/ ? 1 : 0 )`. Similarly if you write `index(str,/regexp/)` you're not comparing the regexp to `str`, you're comparing 1 or 0 to str, like if you wrote `index(str,( $0 ~ /regexp/ ? 1 : 0 ))` - the 2nd arg to index() is not the regexp.

Comment: To be clear - what I'm disputing is [your statement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735128/invalidity-of-awk-printf-in-bash-script#comment1395627_735129) that `you can however pass regexp as the second argument to the index() function too`. In no situation is a regexp passed as the second argument to index().

Comment: @EdMorton understood. thank you so much for detailed explanation! From my understanding it would be then better to return error in all awk implementations for such index() calls with regexp rather than performing `$0 ~ /regexp/` process as it will then cause some false positive result.

Comment: You're welcome. `index(str,/regex/)` gives no more a false positive result than `foo = /regex/` storing `1` or `0` in `foo` is a false positive result, you just have to know when you write `index(str,/regex/)` that `/regex/` in that context means exactly the same thing it does in every other context that doesn't take a regexp arg (e.g. `substr(str,/regex/)` or `foo=/regex/`) and make sure that's what you intended to write.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you again! awk manual has no these deep details as you mentioned. I'm going to open a question so these information can be shared as QnA and I would be appreciated if you can post your explanation as an answer.

Comment: @EdMorton just opened a question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/735194/72456